# Copying files from one directory into another directory using C. Trouble with opening files in the sending directory. No such file or directory

Tags: c, file-io, system

I am brand new to System Programming and am having some trouble learning how directories and files work. The program should take two arguments(directories), if both are existing directories then just copy the files from the first argument into the second. If the second is a file, return with an error, finally if the second argument doesn't exist, then create it and copy the files over.

The problem occurs when I am trying to open each file to copy over the contents to the new created copy. I can get the list of all files in the first directory. If I remove copy the data(aka. in_fd) the program copies all the files over, they just are empty files.

So far the program checks the input, makes the directory if needed. All that is left is to copy over the files.

Any help will be appreciated. I saw this on other questions but none of the answers seemed to help. Thank you in advance for all your help.

```
#define BUFFERSIZE      4096
#define COPYMODE        0644

void oops(char *, char *);

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
int     in_fd, out_fd, n_chars;
char    buf[BUFFERSIZE];
/* check args   */
if ( ac != 3 ){
    fprintf( stderr, "usage: %s source destination\n", *av);
    exit(1);
}

//Directory pointers
DIR *sender_dir_ptr;
DIR *receiver_dir_ptr;

struct dirent *direntp;

//Used to test second argument for new/existing directory
struct stat info;

if(lstat(av[2],&info) != 0) {
    if(errno == ENOENT) {
        //doesn't exist, make directory
        mkdir(av[2], 0700);
        if ((receiver_dir_ptr = opendir(av[2])) == NULL )
            oops("cannot open %s\n", av[2]);

    } else if(errno == EACCES) {
        // we don't have permission to know if
        //  the path/file exists.. impossible to tell
        oops("Permission Denied", av[2]);
    }
}
//so, it exists.
if(S_ISDIR(info.st_mode)) {
    //it's a directory. Assign the directory pointer
    if ((receiver_dir_ptr = opendir(av[2])) == NULL )
        oops("cannot open %s\n", av[2]);
} else if(S_ISREG(info.st_mode)) {
    //it's a file, display error and exit
    oops("File exists but looking for a directory", av[2]);
}


if ((sender_dir_ptr = opendir(av[1])) == NULL )
    oops("cannot open %s\n", av[1]);
else
{
    struct stat st_buf;

    //Go through sender directory and copy over all files to new directory
    while (( direntp = readdir(sender_dir_ptr)) != NULL )
    {
        lstat(direntp->d_name, &st_buf);
        if (S_ISDIR (st_buf.st_mode))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (S_ISREG (st_buf.st_mode))
        {
            printf("direntp= %s\n",direntp->d_name);

            char tmp_in[strlen(av[1])];
            strcpy(tmp_in, av[1]);
            strcat(tmp_in, "/");
            strcat(tmp_in, direntp->d_name);

            if ((in_fd=open(tmp_in, O_RDONLY)) == -1 )
                oops("Cannot open,", direntp->d_name);

            //Create pathname to the second directory
            char* filename = av[2];
            char tmp[strlen(av[2])];
            strcpy(tmp, av[2]);
            strcat(tmp, "/");
            strcat(tmp, direntp->d_name);
            printf("filename: %s \n", tmp);

            //Create new file
            if ((out_fd=creat(tmp, COPYMODE)) == -1 )
                oops( "Cannot creat", tmp);

            //Write old file data into the new files
            while ( (n_chars = read(in_fd , buf, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0 )
                if ( write(out_fd, buf, n_chars ) != n_chars )
                    oops("Write error to ", av[2]);
            if ( n_chars == -1 )
                oops("Read error from ", av[1]);

            //close files
            if ( close(in_fd) == -1 || close(out_fd) == -1 )
                oops("Error closing files","");
        }
        else{
            printf("File: %s \n",direntp->d_name);

        }

    }
    //Close directories
    closedir(sender_dir_ptr);
    closedir(receiver_dir_ptr);
}

return 0;
}

void oops(char *s1, char *s2)
{
fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s ", s1);
perror(s2);
exit(1);
}
```

Comment: No need to `exit(1);` in main. Write `return 1;` instead.

Comment: Doesn't `lstat` need a full path, and not just the filename?  Ditto for `open`?

Comment: @ScottHunter - it does indeed.

Comment: How would you get the full path. If only the directory name is given as an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'direntp->d_name' is filename only, not a complete file specification as required by open() etc.  You need to strcat the name to the folder path.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would up vote you but It will not let me unless I have a reputation of 15 or higher.